# iOS CSR Certificate is not generating correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, certificate

I am creating my first iOS app, and am trying to set up my certificate for push notifications. When I upload my CSR certificate to generate the certificate, I just get a spinning wheel that says, "loading...", which continues for hours. How long should this process take? Am I doing something incorrectly? I have followed a pretty straight-forward tutorial on how to do this, so I don't think I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Reload the page.** Whenever I see this happen for over 5 seconds a quick refresh shows the certificate was already created. Possibly just a bug in Apple's web callbacks...